# Trouble creating a more complex closure

Tags: swift, closures

I am trying to get my head around creating closures. I get the simpler ones like:

```
let squaredNumber = { (num: Int) -> (Int) in 
    return num * num
}

print( squaredNumber(9) ) // 81
```

and I understand how the sorting one works:

```
let team = ["Bob", "Rick", "Peter"]
print( team.sorted() ) // ["Bob", "Peter", "Rick"]
print( team.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 }) ) //["Rick", "Peter", "Bob"]
```

So now I am trying to create my own version of sorting one, in terms of setup.

In the sorting one, there is a plain function `sorted()` and a `sorted(by:...)` option.
The code I am playing with so far is (commented code is just to play with):

```
struct Person {
    
    let name_given = { (fn: String?, ln: String?) -> String in
    
//         return a different value if a nil is supplied
         guard let fn1 = fn else { return "No First Name" }
         guard let ln1 = ln else { return "No Last Name" }
    
//         Only returns value if not nil
//        if let fn1 = fn { return fn1 }
//        if let ln1 = ln { return ln1 }
    
        // returns what has been decided above
        return "\(fn!) \(ln!)"
    }

    let no_name = {() -> String in 
        return "Hello"
    } 
}

let dad = Person()

print( dad.name_given("Jeff", "Smith") )
print( dad.no_name() )
```

but I can only get this to work `dad.something()` but I would like the option of a parameter closure in a function that is I am guessing an optional.

Am I even on the right track in terms of thinking this through.

Basically I want to create a function that execute different code based on wether they have a parameter or not.

So something like `dad()` or `dad(name: {"Jeff", "Smith"})` or `dad(age: {35})`

The closures would combine strings or do something with the code and then return the result or something.

There is no story to the code above, I just want to understand how to create it.

/////////////////

### Edit for clarity:

So I realise my aim was explained with a lot of confusion, because I am trying to figure this out.

Here is hopefully a better attempt:

So this code still doesn't work, but bare with me.

Take for example this:

```
    static func closure(both: (_ a: String, _ b: String) -> String { a, b in
        return "\(a) \(b)"
    })
```

and then this:

```
    static func closure(single: (_ a: String) -> String { a in
        return "\(a)"
    })
```

So then I would effectively be able to do something like this:

```
Person.closure(both: {"First", "Last"}) -> This would output "First Last"
```

and

```
Person.closure(single: {"First"}) -> This would output "First"
```

My outcome would be that I could have a static class that has a bunch of closures, but that are grouped.

So if I want to a bunch of string type closures, it would be easy to find them because you could do something like:

```
StaticStruct.string(<thing1>: {<closure params>})
StaticStruct.string(<thing2>: {<closure params>})
StaticStruct.string(<thing3>: {<closure params>})
```

or if I want to do something with numbers, it would be:

```
StaticStruct.numbers(<thing1>: {<closure params>})
StaticStruct.numbers(<thing2>: {<closure params>})
StaticStruct.numbers(<thing3>: {<closure params>})
```

I hope this makes more sense.

I like the way it looks when you do an array sort, that is why I started thinking like this.

Comment: When sorting a collection what you need is to input two elements and return a bool. If you take a look at its declaration you need to pass a predicate called `areInIncreasingOrder` `(Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool`

Comment: Btw where do you want the `nil` elements to be returned at the begin or the end of the collection?

Comment: It is not about creating a collection, in the example I would like to join the names, so that if I have 2 names `(fn,ln)` then it would output `fn+" "+ln` but if there is only one then have it only put in one. But I don't want to have to put in `nil` as a parameter. but in addition to that I would like to have other options as well based on the requirements. So I want mutliple functions with closures, but part of a parent function. I think that is how I am processing it.

Comment: `"But I don't want to have to put in nil as a parameter"` AFAIK there is no way to pass only one parameter when it expects two.

Comment: `dad(name: {"Jeff", "Smith"})` is not valid Swift syntax, can you elaborate more on how you'd want to call the method? Maybe give us some samples of call sites and outputs you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is flawed for Swift:

If you don't provide anything at all, not even `nil`, how can Swift know what's missing?

Think about this example:

```
print( dad.name_given("Connor") )
```

How can Swift know if you provided only the first name, or only the last name? In your example, you will need to be specific on what is *not* provided:

```
print( dad.name_given(nil, "Connor") )    // Surely only last name is provided
```

A function would solve this problem by providing a **default value** to the parameters, so you don't have to pass `nil`, but then you would need to specifically tell what you're passing, or Swift will assume:

```
func person(fn: String? = "", ln: String? = "") -> String {...}
print( dad.person(ln: "Connor"))    // Surely passing the second parameter

func person(_ fn: String? = "", _ ln: String? = "") -> String {...}
print( dad.person("Connor"))   // It will assume that you are passing the first parameter
```

But with closures, you can't provide a default value to parameters:

```
let name_given = { (fn: String? = "", ln: String? = "") -> String in...}
// Error: Default arguments are not allowed in closures
```

It might not solve your problem, but you can create a function that provides default values to the parameters (no need to pass `nil`), and accepts a closure to treat those parameters.

```
    func describe(fn: String = "", ln: String = "", _ action: @escaping (String?, String?)->String) -> String {
        let first: String? = fn == "" ? nil : fn
        let second: String? = ln == "" ? nil : ln
        return action(first, second)
    }

print( dad.describe(ln: "Connor", dad.name_given))   // No first Name
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation - I added more info on what I am after. i hope it makes sense.